workerize-loader npm package returns error [not cacheable] during runtime with webpack 5
I'm doing a major upgrade of all packages for my react application. This includes upgrading every package to its latest version. In order to make my upgrades work, I'm using webpack 5 with CRACO to run my application.
I've gotten to the point where I can successfully build my application. However, when I try to run my app locally (using craco start), then I get a weird message in my terminal

This is something that only happens when I RE-start my application. If I remove the node_modules and package-lock, then reinstall, and then run this. I don't get this error
Because of this, I'm getting weird runtime errors in my local app:

I've checked many times and there is nothing wrong with my code for the file fetchWorker. Need whatever help I can get please.
I expect my application to run locally without any runtime errors everytime.
